# Should one Share their Latex Documents on GitHub

Tags: git

I am not sure if this question exactly fits here, but this is the best to my judgement.

I understand GitHub is mainly for posting hobby (or commercial) programming projects . I was wondering, does it make sense to share Latex related documents on GitHub public profiles.

Comment: Yes and no -- it depends on the content of the `LaTeX` document, and the structure (self-written packages etc?) Perhaps, it is better to provide the `pdf` - version of the document rather, unless there is cooperative writting of a group on the same document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

git works fine with LaTeX (almost any text-based source, in fact), so why not? I'm using git for almost everything I write (mostly not shared, some pushed to a git server for backup, others locally shared), and also to work with my students on their theses (mostly reading what they write, sometimes sending a git patch for their consideration). On a project we had a set of BibTeX files with the references for our papers and general references used in our writings, all shared though git. We set up a private git server for this.

You can pay for having private repositories on github, AFAIU. Or you can use their free service to share stuff under an open license with the world. Just make sure you really want to give up your rights in the second case. Perhaps think about what the [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org) licenses would mean for your work, check what github asks from you.

Comment: [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) allows you to have free private repos as well.

Comment: As for 8th May 2019, GitHub allows unlimited private repositories.